# Hiding context menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

One of my plugins depends on WST which has 'Validate' menu item. I tried hiding this menu item using activities, but so far was no successful. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Using plug-in spy, I am pretty sure menu is contributed by org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ui.ValidationMenuAction

Here is what I did:

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
  <activity
        id="com.iwaysoftware.integration.tools.validationActivity"
        name="validation activity">
  </activity>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="com.iwaysoftware.integration.tools.validationActivity"
        pattern="org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui/org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ui.ValidationMenuAction">
  </activityPatternBinding>
  <category
        id="com.iwaysoftware.integration.tools.validationCategory"
        name="validation category">
  </category>
  <categoryActivityBinding
        activityId="com.iwaysoftware.integration.tools.validationActivity"
        categoryId="com.iwaysoftware.integration.tools.validationCategory">
  </categoryActivityBinding>
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I think we may be running into a bug in Eclipse 4: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=381765

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to remove the validate option is to remove following 3 jars from your plugins folder:
    org.eclipse.wst.validation.infopop_1.0.300.v201309101952.jar
    org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui_1.2.500.v201310231452.jar
    org.eclipse.wst.validation_1.2.600.v201501211647.jar